# It's possible to create multiple instances of Firestore database inside a single console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

It's possible to create multiple instances of Firestore Database(one for each project) inside the same console in Firebase? I saw that it's possible to do it for Firebase Realtime Database, but I don't see the possibility to do it for Firestore.

Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Edit July 21 2023:

Google Cloud (and Firebase) now allow the creation of multiple databases per project.  Read more in the [announcement](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/manage-multiple-firestore-databases-in-a-project).

The Firebase CLI has [new commands to work with Firestore instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands).

---

Original answer:

It is not possible to have two instances of Firestore in a project.  Database sharding in Realtime Database is possible (and many times necessary) because of its scaling limitations.  Firestore does not have the same scalaing limitations (it is what's called "massively scalable"), so you should be able to store all your project's data in a single instance.

Comment: The only caveat being that while in beta, a Firestore instance cannot surpass 1 million concurrent connections and 10,000 read/write operations/second. There is no way to break these barriers while in beta.

Comment: Doug, this unfortunately causes problems for automated testing solutions in an integration/system test environment.  I would like the ability during my automated tests to create Firebase database instance, populate it with data, possibly clear and repopulate that data regularly during the test, then drop the database after the tests are complete.  I have one integration test environment for each feature branch. To achieve this kind of functionality, I have to create an entire Google Project and enable with with Firebase (which I can't figure out how to do completely headless). Suggestions?

Comment: is this answer still true in 2020?

Comment: @Ahsath Firestore still scales massively and doesn't require any sharding.

Comment: @DougStevenson While I understand the scaling aspect of Firestore and the fact that we can easily just create multiple projects for different environments, I'm wondering how could we deal with SSO (single sign-ons) for multiple websites (with same structure but different content).

We've been using Firebase Auth because it was just easier to deal with. But since multiple Firestore instances will not be a thing, gues we need to port to our own auth mechanism? Any other ideas are welcome, thanks!

Comment: As of July 2023, this feature is now available: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/manage-multiple-firestore-databases-in-a-project